# Java platformer game performance

Tags: java, performance, graphics, frame-rate

I recently started working on a 2d platformer in java, and am asking a performance related question.

In my game, I have a world (relatively small for now).

But over half+ of the world isn't visible to the players camera, however I'm still painting the entire world (even the unseen parts).

Here's what I'm doing right now.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.translate(player.camX(), player.camY());

    for (GameObject gameObject : solidObjects){
        if (gameObject.isTouching(player.getCameraRect()))
            gameObject.paint(g);
    }

    player.paint(g);

    for (GameObject gameObject : unSolidObjects){
        if (gameObject.isTouching(player.getCameraRect()))
            gameObject.paint(g);
    }

}
```

So the question is, would it be faster having an if-statement checking if its on the screen before painting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Doing a check to see if it's on a screen should take no more than 1 or 2 steps.

Painting everything requires you to draw every single pixel on to the screen regardless of whether it's used or not.

Answer (score 1):

If `gameObject.paint(g);` involves a lot of drawing calls, most likely the branching (check) would save more work than it costs. If it's only like one drawing call to paint a sprite though, your library would already perform such a check to avoid buffer overruns and yours would be redundant.

That said, if you are starting to face performance issues here, then I recommend using some kind of data structure. A simple one is a grid like so:

[image]

When your elements move, remove them from the grid cells they occupy and insert them to the new one(s) they occupy. That should just involve manipulating a few integers if you implement this efficiently.

Then when you want to draw elements on the screen, only draw the elements in the grid cells that overlap. That'll prevent you from looping over every single element in the game world. This also comes in handy for accelerated collision detection if you need it.

A quad-tree is an alternative though a little bit more costly to update, but it can provide better search quality if the elements in your game are sparsely distributed.